# How to use output from previous line in Plot?

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, output

Suppose, I want to solve a equation and want to obtain it's first root. In this case I've used

```
In[1]=:Solve[b^2 + b*z + 1 == 0, b][[1]]
```

This gives

```
Out[2]={b -> 1/2 (-z - Sqrt[-4 + z^2])}
```

Now I want use this result directly in Plot command. My code for this is

```
In[3]:Plot[Out[2], {z, -1000, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

But I'm not getting the plot. If I use

```
In[4]:Plot[1/2 (-z - Sqrt[-4 + z^2]), {z, -1000, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I'm getting the plot correctly. I guess in In[3], `Out[2]` contains `b->`, that's why it's unable to plot. How to handle this situation?

p.s. This is a prototype of my actual problem. I want to solve this in this way because  my output is too large to copy and paste in the `Plot` command.

Comment: Try `Plot[%[[1, 2]], {z, -1000, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]`! Taking second part of the `Rule` is the trick. You can also use `Plot[Out[1][[1, 2]], {z, -1000, 1000}, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: @PlatoManiac. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I would strongly advise against this suggestion (i.e., using % or Out). It makes repeating the results when you re-run your notebook dependent on the order of execution. When you are going to use the results of a calculation assign a variable to that result.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Thx for pointing out the pitfall with `Out` or `%`. I though assumed the OP will understand this ordering issue himself while playing with the notebook and if not through the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to define the solution as

```
sol = Solve[b^2 + b*z + 1 == 0, b][[1]];
```

and then plot using the strategy suggested in the Help file for `Solve`, which replaces the variable in the rule (in this case `b`) with the desired solution:

```
Plot[b /. sol, {z, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bill s.  Now if I've a quartic equation in 'b', and want to plot all four the roots together what will be the syntax in that case?

Comment: I think I've got it. 'Plot[b/.{sol1,sol2,sol3,sol4},.....]' It's working for me.